# why is javascript turning my date into a type of number

Tags: javascript

I am running into a problem with when I try to pass a Date() variable I have created to a function that I working on, if I put the following in the function I have passed the variable to this is what I see.

```
 console.log("quickScreenCompletedDate: " + typeof quickScreenCompletedDate);
 console.log("quickScreenCompletedDate: " + quickScreenCompletedDate);
```

here is the output

```
"quickScreenCompletedDate: number" 
"quickScreenCompletedDate: 1403409600000"
```

However when I create the variable I am creating it as a Date() class

```
var completedDate = Date.parse('@Model.CompletedDate');
```

then I call the function like this.

```
 previousDenialDate_ChangeHandler(isChild, completedDate);
```

for completeness here is the function definition

```
function checkIfShouldShowPreviouslyDeniedMessage(isChild, quickScreenCompletedDate) {
```

The problem is that i need to do some logic on the compeletedDate var and that works just fine as you can see I am getting the number 1403409600000, now though, I also need to display this to the user and when I try to call toDateString() that fails as it isn't a date object anymore. What am I missing that is causing this.

Thanks

Comment: JavaScript stores dates as milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

Comment: Why not create a `new Date()` out of the number after you're done performing your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

So:

```
var completedDate = Date.parse('2014-07-01');
```

returns `1404172800000` (of type number)

---

Instead, do:

```
var completedDate = new Date('@Model.CompletedDate');
```

which will give you an actual Date object instance.

Comment: I up-voted faby and codingWithSpike - codingWithSpike gets the win for having the simpler version. :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript stores dates as milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You do the math in milliseconds and then convert to a date using toDateString() to print it as a date OR you can create a new Date and pass in the milliseconds to the constructor.

**Example**

```
new Date(1403409600000);
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try with `new Date`?

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

in your case try

```
var completedDate = new Date('@Model.CompletedDate.Year','@Model.CompletedDate.Month','@Model.CompletedDate.Day');
```

or

```
var completedDate = new Date('@YourModelVariable');
```

If you use `Date.parse` Beware of timezone issues

```
var d = Date.parse("10/22/2014");
```

refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for documentation of `Date.parse`

Comment: Note that `new Date()` will call `Date.parse()` for you internally, so `new Date(Date.parse('@YourModelVariable'))` can be simplified to `new Date('@YourModelVariable')`